# To avoid null/undefined references: when to use a Safe Navigation Operator (?.) and when to use a Logical AND (&&) operator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, performance, testing

Consider that I have an object property (say `arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined: SomeObjType`) in my angular component.

I want to perform some array operation (say `filter()` operation) on it's `data: DataType[]` object and store the value in some other property (say `filteredArr: DataType[]`) as shown below

```
this.filteredArr = this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined.data.filter(item => this.someFilterCondition(item));
```

To avoid any TypeErrors (i.e., any `undefined` or `null` references) I could choose either of the below approches to write the code.

**Approach 1: *Use a Safe operator (?.)***

```
this.filteredArr = this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined?.data?.filter(item => this.someFilterCondition(item));
```

or

**Approach 2: *Use logical and operator (&&)***

```
if(this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined && this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined.data) {
    this.filteredArr = this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined.data.filter(item => this.someFilterCondition(item))
}
```

My Queries:

1. **When should we use the either of the approaches?**
2. **Which approach is the best to follow (or avoid) by default?**

Comment: `?.` isn't safe in all circumstances. `a?.b` will still error if `a` is undefined.

Comment: One difference: when the value is `undefined`, the first example `this.filteredArr` will be assigned `undefined`, whereas the second example will not assign `this.filteredArr`.

Comment: how about: `if(this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined?.data) {  this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined.data.filter(item => this.someFilterCondition(item)); }`
You ensure var is set and dont have to repeat same statment over and over. Might look like situation 1 at first, but now you can handle the else statement as you like

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, optional chaining will not error, it handles both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: You say you have an array. What is `.data` then?

Comment: @Bergi it does in the very specific case I mentioned.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No? `const a = undefined; console.log(a?.b);` does not error.

Comment: @Bergi that's a good example. `const a = undefined` defines `a`. Without it, `a?.b` throws a reference error

Comment: @evolutionxbox Please say "not defined" or "undeclared" if that's what you mean, not "undefined" which is commonly understood as "the `undefined` value" or to be ambiguous at best.

Comment: @Bergi will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Typescript or only care about newer browsers that support optional chaining there is no need to use `&&` anymore. You can just use `.?` all the time.

You may also want to use `??` (*nullish coalescing*) to default to an empty array so that `filteredArray` will never be `undefined` when optional chaining results in an:

```js
this.filteredArr = this.arrThatCouldBeNullOrUndefined?.data?.filter(...) ?? [];
```